# Empty query result with wrapPageElement

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I had my graphql query from contentful and decided to try out wrapPageElement to provide list of estates everywhere in my app, but sadly after extracting query to a provider I'm unable to get any data from it. Any ideas why it is not working now?

gatsby-browser.js

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "@components/layout/layout"
import EstatesProvider from "@context/estatesProvider"

const wrapPageElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <EstatesProvider>
      <Layout>{element}</Layout>
    </EstatesProvider>
  )
}

export default wrapPageElement
```

estatesProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext } from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

export const EstatesContext = createContext({})

const EstatesProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const query = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MyQuery {
      allContentfulEstate {
        edges {
          node {
            thumbnailUrl
            name
            childContentfulEstateDescriptionRichTextNode {
              json
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  const estates = query.allContentfulEstate.edges

  return (
    <EstatesContext.Provider value={estates}>
      {children}
    </EstatesContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default EstatesProvider
```

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { EstatesContext } from "@context/estatesProvider"

const AllEstates = () => {
  const estates = useContext(EstatesContext)
  return <>{console.log(estates)}</>
}

export default AllEstates
```

**I managed to solve it with**

```
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <EstatesProvider>{element}</EstatesProvider>
}

const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <Layout>{element}</Layout>
}

export default wrapRootElement
```

Have no idea why it is working this way, someone can tell me?
Provider cant be in wrapRootElement it is also causing errors,which is recommended in Gatsby browser api docs.